# ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node instances grow and JVM throws OOM

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I am using ConcurrentLinkedQueue in a Producer-Consumer scenario. My producer is a Singleton called by all methods in my application: Producer.getInstance().add("foo"); and the add() method calls the ConcurrentLinkedQueue offer method.

```
public void add(String message) {
    myQueue.offer(message);
}
```

Otherwise, I have my Consumer running in an other thread and simply calling the poll method on the ConcurrentLinkedQueue inside the Producer.

**Edit:**

Add code between if ((buffer = myQueue.poll()) != null) { }

CRActiveMQProducer is a Singleton which initializes a connection to my ActiveMQ server and send message with the send() method.

```
private StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

public void run() {
    while(condition) {
        String buffer = null;
        if ((buffer = myQueue.poll()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(buffer);
            numberMessage++;
            if (numberMessage >= 10000) {
                CRActiveMQProducer.getInstance().send(stringBuffer.toString());
                stringBuffer = stringBuffer.delete(0, stringBuffer.length());
                numberMessage = 0L;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call the Producer add() method like 50 Million times (yeah it's huge but it's just 2,5% of the number of called which should be done)

Anyway, I got a OutOfMemory Exception, I try to read the heap dump with VisualVM and I figure out that this OOM was caused by the huge number of ConcurrentLinkedQueue$Node instances (more than 30Millions).
I think I have a new node for each offer() or poll() methods call, but not 100% sure (can't able to load the full heap dump...).

Do you think this is a normal behaviour of ConcurrentLinkedQueue ? Or just me doing something wrong ? Thanks!

Comment: how often is myQueue.poll() actually getting called?  Are you sure you are reaching that code and that the thread isn't getting starved for resources?

Comment: @jjathman MyQueue.poll() is called 50Millions time

Comment: Can you post the code in the "do something with buffer" section?

Comment: Two suggestions since you updated your code.  First, maybe try using StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer unless your run method is being called from multiple threads which it doesn't sound like it is.  Second, try initializing your StringBuffer/Builder to a more reasonable size to start.  Like 10000 * sizeOfAvgMessageOnQueue.  So if each object on your queue is 10 characters than I would start my buffer at 100,000 characters long

Answer (score 0):

The queue obvously has to store all the elements you put in the queue, and it does that using nodes which are linked with each other. That's the principle of a linked queue. Your producer produces itels too fast, and the consumer doesn't have the time to consume them, so in the end, you end up with an OOM.

You should consider using a bound BlockingQueue: it would force the producer thread to block when the queue contains too many elements, avoiding OOMs.

Comment: Thanks but I really need the producer to be as fast as possible because I don't want my application begin slow because of the millions call. But I will try it.

Comment: I got the same issue with the amount of LinkedBlockingQueue$Node instances :(

Comment: Bear in mind that if you use a bounded queue, the "offer" method might return without actually putting anything into the queue.  It simply offer to put something in.  If it can fit the element, it returns true, otherwise it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Couple suggestions:

1. Add much more memory to your application. Try something like `-Xmx2g`
2. Try adding additional threads to read from the queue
3. Make the "do something with buffer" as fast as possible
4. Spin off "do something with buffer" in to its own thread (probably using a threadpool) to
   keep it from blocking reading more from the queue

Have you timed everything within the reader service to see how long it takes?  If you really are putting things on your queue faster than you can read them off then you need to find ways of speeding the reader(s) up.  You running out of memory is just a **side effect** of the real problem.  The problem is you aren't processing the queued up work fast enough.

Comment: Thanks, The first one is not acceptable (Like I said, 30Millions call is just 2,5% of the number of calls)

I could add threads to read from the queue but I have to be sure that the messages read and push in ActiveMQ are in the exact same order
I will try to append less data in my StringBuffer, I'll tell you if it's working.

Comment: How much memory are you currently using?

Comment: OK, that seems like it should always be adequate.  Really your only choice is to get the reader(s) to be faster then.  If you need to push things on to the queue as quickly as possible, then you need to read them faster.  You may need to go to more of a distributed architecture, have one queue writer but multiple queue readers from several servers